# Why my Apple Ad hoc or distribution profile not allowing to install app on all devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I am developing one app need to distribute across the stakeholders so I am using adhoc profile but its not working on all devices?

Comment: Have you added all devices to your ad-hoc profile. Need some more inputs.

Comment: Using a paritcular Provisioning Profile you can only run an application on those devices registered. Please verify if those devices were checked while creating the Provisioning profile. If not, add those devices and edit the profiles to include those and rebuild using this new profile.

Comment: I am using Adhoc not developent So it should work with any device or not?

Comment: @user3465497 If you have `In House` option while generating Distribution profile then only you can install on any device. If its AdHoc you can install on devices which are added in the profile.

Comment: You are right.There are 2 type of account iOS developer and iOS In-house Developer.https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/

Answer (score 1):

Did your add test devices's uuid into your ad hoc profile?

Make sure each step has been done when making a profile.

Add devices uuid -> Build iOS Provisioning Profiles -> Build your app as (develop or release) -> Archive -> Get ipa file

Finally,send your stakeholders ipa file and provision profile.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: But the Adhoc should work with all the devices whether its added to Portal or Not?

Comment: @user3465497: You are fundamentally misunderstanding the Ad Hoc distribution process - read it up here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html. You have to specify the UDIDs of the test devices (there can be up to 100 per apple developer account).

Comment: @TheEye thanks guy.You have post the link that I think.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 type of Developer program.
1. iOS Developer
2. iOS Developer Enterprise

See the link 
https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/